# pimcore: updating objects with localized fields

Tags: object, controller, updating, localized, pimcore

I have a weird problem when updating objects in pimcore.
I've created a class containing some normal and also localized fields and then some objects from that class. 
It is possible to edit all objects directly via pimcore, but the only ones which can be updated through controllers are the ones where all localized fields are filled, although some of these fields may not be used in the form. That is, an object won't be updated unless all its localized fields are filled before.

Any hints?

EDITED:

Here is a piece of code from my controller :

```
$newTitle = Object_TitleArchive::getById(251);
$newTitle->setName('New Name'); 
$newTitle->save();
```

It does not work unless all localized fields of the object are filled before or given now.

Revision: 3086

Comment: You will likely get better responses if you show some code to give context for your question.

Comment: Please specify on which version of pimcore you observed this behavior.

Comment: Do you have a language specified on the document where the controller is run from? If that's not the issue, a possible workaround could be to specify a default value to the localized field when you update the object. (You can also specify a language as such: $newTitle->setName('New Name',$locale);

Comment: is it a mandatory field? if so, all language versions of this field need to be filled in.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a mandatory-field-problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check under `Settings -> Object -> Classes`, and then under the class you have defined. If the components placed under the localized field has the checkbox `Mandatory Field` checked, remove that check or fill in values for all required languages.